# Relative acidity of aqueous LiF, SnCl2, and YCl3

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution

Which one of the following salts make the highest and lowest pH when dissolved in water?
$$\ce{LiF, SnCl2, YCl3}$$

My approach was :
considering the corresponding aqua acids, the order of acidity should be $\ce{Li(H2O)_n+ < Sn(H2O)_n^2+ < Y(H2O)_n^3+}$ and $\ce{F-}$ is less stable than $\ce{Cl-}$. So $\ce{LiF}$ is the weakest acid and $\ce{YCl3}$ the strongest.

But considering aqua acid looks weird (do they exist?) and I cannot be sure this of solution. I don't even know the right answer. Can anyone give some help?

Comment: Hi, that's absolutely beautiful formatting, but [please don't use MathJax in titles on chem.SE](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/261/is-mathjax-in-titles-a-problem-and-why). And, regarding the question, I would expect the same trend that you have described.

Comment: Yes, acidity of aquocomplexes is important here but it's more tricky than just charge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salt solutions are acidic because of [hydrolysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrolysis#Metal_aqua_ions).

LiF is obviously neutral, because it's a salt of very strong acid and very strong base.

Ironically, Wikipedia is wrong about Sn<sup>2+</sup>: it's much more acidic in water than Ca<sup>2+</sup> or Zn<sup>2+</sup>, and more acidic than Y<sup>3+</sup>, 
because Sn<sup>2+</sup> forms very stable and non-soluble hydroxo compounds and hence readily undergoes hydrolysis.

The answer is: LiF < YCl<sub>3</sub> < SnCl<sub>2</sub>

Table data:

YCl<sub>3</sub> has pH 4.5-5.8 ([source](http://www.espimetals.com/index.php/msds/773-yttrium-chloride-hydrate)),
SnCl<sub>2</sub> has pH 1-2 (source [1](http://www.emdmillipore.com/US/en/product/Tin(II)-chloride-dihydrate,MDA_CHEM-107815), [2](http://www.ch.ntu.edu.tw/~genchem99/msds/exp10/SnCl2.pdf)).

Comment: I can’t start to explain how wrong it is to define deprotonation of aquacomplexes as hydrolysis (even if Wikipedia does so). Also, $\ce{LiF}$ is not the salt of ‘a very strong acid and a very strong base’.

Comment: Well, if you can't start to explain your thoughts about hydrolysis, then at least explain why LiF is not a salt of strong acid and strong base.

Comment: Because neither is $\ce{HF}$ a strong acid nor is $\ce{Li-}$ — if that would even make sense — a strong base (You could argue about $\ce{LiOH}$, but that only semi made up the salt). On hydrolysis: It is the *lysis* (i.e. splitting) of a compound *via* the action of water. However, the acidic action in solution is not due to any lysis of any kind except for protolysis (displacement of a proton). The aqua ligands remain coordinated to the Lewis acid with one aqua ligand transforming itself (autolyticly!) into a hydroxido ligand.

Answer (score 0):

A basic salt is formed when a weak acid reacts with a strong base. $\ce{LiF}$ is formed from strong base $\ce{LiOH}$ and weak acid $\ce{HF}$ to give a basic salt.

$\ce{HF}$ is not a strong acid.

Comment: I attempted to restore intended formatting; please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown. Also it seems like the answer is only partial; feel free to elaborate on two remaining compounds to make it complete.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! To help you become acquainted with the site, I would just like to suggest if you haven't already, please take a minute to look over the [help center](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) and [tour page](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) to better understand our guidelines and question policies. You will find StackExchange (SE) to be a different kind of Q&A website from the mainstream. To learn more visit [Meta.Chemistry](http://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/), [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/), or [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229)